# How to access "Choose Color Scheme" Programmatically

Tags: front-end, color, gui-construction

I am designing an App and I want to use the "Choose Color Scheme" tools inside Button.

[image]

I am looking to have this tool in popup window when the Button is clicked but I can't find the command to get this tools.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: closely related: [RGBColor, ColorSlider and ColorSetter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88325/5478)

Comment: R.M.'s great answer to [(67212)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67212/121) is worth looking at as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean

```
Button[
 Tooltip["click", 
  Column[{"Click this button to select a ColorScheme.", 
    "This button will be replaced with ColorData"}]],
 With[{box = EvaluationBox[]}, SelectionMove[box, All, Expression];
  FrontEndExecute@
   FrontEnd`AttachCell[box, 
    FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"], {1, {Right, Top}}, {Left, Top}, 
   "ClosingActions" -> {"SelectionDeparture", "ParentChanged", "EvaluatorQuit"}]]]
```

[image: GIF]

---

Based on [a comment by the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120999/how-to-access-choose-color-scheme-programmatically/121000?noredirect=1#comment327974_121000) a `PopupMenu` might be more suitable.

```
DynamicModule[{colorScheme = "Rainbow"}, 
 Row[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[colorScheme], 
    Thread[ColorData["Gradients"] -> 
      MapThread[
       Column[{Style[#1, 9], #2}, Left, 0] &, 
       {ColorData["Gradients"],
         LinearGradientImage[#, {700, 100}] & /@ ColorData["Gradients"]}]]], 
   Spacer[10], 
   Dynamic[colorScheme]}]]
```

[image: GIF2]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but one thing to mention here is when the Color Scheme is selected the Button is gone. So what is the point of using Button then? Isn't the Button should be there and the selected Color Scheme is assigned to variable.

Comment: The problem is that the selector is set to disappear once you pick a color, @Algohi. (Try it out yourself: `CellPrint[FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]]` and then pick a color scheme you want before clicking "OK".) It would need to be modified if you want it to be persistent; e.g. `CellPrint[
 FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] /. _NotebookDelete :> Sequence[]]`.

Comment: @Algohi there is nothing about any variable in the question.

Comment: @Algohi I can only add to the other comments that your question needs more context and a description of the desired behavior.

Comment: FWIW: the *complete* list of available gradients is in ``DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeNames``.

Comment: I only noticed your update now.  I see what you were getting at with regard to "ColorSchemeSelector" now.  I do like that.  Your use of `Pane` causes the gradients to not be fully displayed however; why did you add that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That was just an oversight. The `ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit"` option for `Panel` was missing. I updated the answer with a version that uses `LinearGradientImage` instead of `ColorData["Gradients", "Image"]` for more sizing flexibility.

Comment: Faster resizing method: `ColorData["Gradients", 
  "Image"] /. {(AspectRatio -> _) -> 
   AspectRatio -> 1/4, (ImageSize -> _) -> ImageSize -> 150}`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a modification of Karsten's answer attempting to get the behavior you described in a comment.

- The selected value is assigned to `` Global`$color `` (as shown by `Dynamic`)
- I made the picker wider to get rid of the annoying bottom scroll bar

Code:

```
Button["Pick a color",
 Module[{picker, box = EvaluationBox[]},

  picker = FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"] /. {
     _FrontEndExecute :> (Global`$color = First @ $CellContext`gsel$$),
     {180, Automatic} -> {195, Automatic}
   };

  SelectionMove[box, All, Expression];

  FrontEnd`AttachCell[box, picker, {1, {Right, Top}}, {Left, Top}
    , "ClosingActions" -> {"SelectionDeparture", "ParentChanged", "EvaluatorQuit"}
  ] // FrontEndExecute

 ]
]

Dynamic[Global`$color]
```

[image]

---

In a comment below [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) offered a cleaner implementation using a [`DialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DialogInput.html); here is a copy for preservation and easier reading. (comments lose tabulation.)

(Now with a correction from Karsten.)

```
Button["Pick a color",
  $color =
    DialogInput[
      RawBoxes @ FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"][[1, 1]] /. {
       _FrontEndExecute :> DialogReturn[First @ $CellContext`gsel$$],
       {180, Automatic} -> {195, Automatic},
       _NotebookDelete  :> DialogReturn[$Canceled]
      }
    ]
  , Method -> "Queued"
]
```

Comment: Or something like: ``Button["Pick a color", 
 c$olor = DialogInput[
   RawBoxes[
     FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"][[1, 
       1]]] /. {_FrontEndExecute :> (DialogReturn[
        First@$CellContext`gsel$$]), {180, Automatic} -> {195, 
       Automatic}}]
 ,
 
 Method -> "Queued"
 
 ]`` though I'm not sure why does it take so long to initialize.

Comment: @Kuba Well that's cleaner, isn't it?  I wonder if I had started with a blank slate if I would have arrived at that.  Anyway the "pop-up" behavior of Karsten's method which I built upon might be desired by some so I'll leave it as is.  Are you going to post that as an answer?

Comment: No, it is too similar to yours, feel free to incorporate it if you think it can be useful. I don't know what is needed but I felt that this approach is closer to old generic Mathematica's features.

Comment: There is almost no point in using the `"ColorSchemeSelector"` in the `DialogInput` version. It's just a `PopupMenu` and a ´ListPicker`.

Comment: @Karsten7 I don't think I understand.  One would have to construct that dialog with a drop-down menu for Gradients, Physical, and Indexed, and then the actual `ListPicker` menus themselves.   Why on Earth would one *not* start with `FrontEndResource["ColorSchemeSelector"]` in this case?

Comment: You can add `_NotebookDelete :> DialogReturn[$Canceled]` to the list of replacement rules to fix the **Cancel** button.

Comment: @Karsten7 Good catch on Kuba's modification!  I'll add that to his code.

Comment: [See](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3om7O.png). Not much more code, but much more responsive.

Comment: Btw, instead of increasing the size you could reduce the `FrameMargins` using for example `(FrameMargins -> _) -> FrameMargins -> 0`.